# Group members add their location to OSM map?

Tags: openstreetmap, markers

We have a Facebook group with about 100,000 members. How can we create an OpenStreetMap map where members who have the URL to the map can add their location with a marker (only one marker per member), but not edit the map settings or change markers that other members have added?